# Linear Algebra Help Complex Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

For a general $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with column vectors $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and row vectors $r_1,r_2,r_3$ when does a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ exist such that

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} c_1c_2 \end{pmatrix} B \; \begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ r_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

where (c1 c2) is a 3x2 matrix, B a 2x2 square matrix, and (r1/r2) a 2x3 matrix.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry! I formatted the question wrongly. It should be c1 and c2 as a 3x2 matrix and r1 and r2 as a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: A hint: $rank(A) \le 2$ (I think it is a necessary and sufficient condition). Tell how you can exploit this hint.

Comment: Have you studied Singular Value Decomposition ?

Comment: Any comment ?.... Any personal work to show ?...

Comment: I have heard of SVD before but don't have too many clues on it. Can you tell me more? I have unfortunately resorted to brute solving this and almost tore out my hair... Should you say that rank(A) is less or equal to 2, then that would tell me that it is possible to reduce A to a line/dot/nothing in row/column space. Would it then be possible to back solve for A using the reduced echelon form of A and a matrix B?

Comment: The example that came with the problem was a 3x3 matrix A, r1  = (1, 3, 8), r2 =(1, 2, 6), r3 = (0, 1, 2). Then det(A) = 0 and rank(A)=2. Then the matrix B would in fact exist according to your hint.

Comment: But here's the thing, SVD causes the middle matrix to be a partially diagonal matrix with a bunch of zero entries. I think that reduced SVD would be a little more useful in this case.